# Fixing Ambiguous Column in WHERE Clause

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, ajax, ambiguous

I need to display a table that corresponds to the value chosen after I select a value in a dropdown list. If I run this query in my SQLPro Studio, and obviously without the `$mr_id` variable, it says that `MR_ID` is ambiguous. Is there a way to fix this? This seems like a small problem to me but I can't seem to figure it out. I just need to make sure there is a `WHERE` clause somewhere so that it will only display the values that correlate to the value selected.

The table is only 2 columns, `MR_ID` (which is what is displayed in the dropdown list and also concatenated with another column not in the table) and `Supp_ID`.

```
<?php
$host="xxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
$dbName="xxxxx"; 
$dbUser="xxxxxxxx"; 
$dbPass="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$mr_id = $_POST['mr_id'];

$dbh = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=".$host."; Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$sql_one = "
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(Stage_Rebate_Index.MR_ID AS INT),' - ', Stage_Rebate_Master.MR_Name) AS MR_ID,
       Stage_Rebate_Index.MR_ID AS sort_column, 
       CAST(Supp_ID as INT) AS Supp_ID
FROM   Stage_Rebate_Index
  LEFT JOIN Stage_Rebate_Master 
    ON Stage_Rebate_Master.MR_ID = Stage_Rebate_Index.MR_ID
WHERE  Stage_Rebate_Index.MR_ID = '$mr_id'
ORDER BY sort_column";


//$users = $dbh->query($sql);
$users_one = $dbh->query($sql_one);
?>

<html>
    <body>

        <!-- Table -->
<p> 
    <div id="table_div">
        <table border="1" id="index_table" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
            <thead>
                <tr class="ui-widget-header">
                <td>MR ID</td>
                <td>Supplier ID</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php foreach($users_one->fetchAll() as $supp) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="mr_id"><?php echo $supp['MR_ID'];?></td>
                <td class="supp_id"><?php echo $supp['Supp_ID'];?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

EDIT:
Updated query with harcoded value...

```
$sql_one = "
SELECT 
       CONCAT(CAST(t1.MR_ID AS INT),' - ', COALESCE(t2.MR_Name, '')) AS MR_ID,
       t1.MR_ID AS sort_column, 
       CAST(Supp_ID as INT) AS Supp_ID
FROM Stage_Rebate_Index t1
      LEFT JOIN Stage_Rebate_Master t2
         ON t2.MR_ID = t1.MR_ID
WHERE  
  CONCAT(CAST(t1.MR_ID AS INT),' - ', t2.MR_Name) = LTRIM(RTRIM('1 - Company A'))
ORDER BY sort_column";
```

Comment: Update the question and remove **everything** that **isn't** related to your question. If you ask about SQL - remove all html/css/javascript from your question.

Comment: you should start using alias for your table names, that would make this much easier

Answer (score 3):

In your where clause

```
WHERE
    MR_ID = '$mr_id'
```

Specify the table you want it from as such:

```
WHERE
    Stage_Rebate_Master.MR_ID = '$mr_id'
```

You should probably also specify the tables in your select clause too.

Comment: This is good in that it gets rid of my ambiguous column, but this concatenated value is not in the Stage_Rebate_Index or Master table...its just a join between the 2

Comment: Change the alias in the select statement to not match the column name, then use it in the where.  That or use the entire concatenation formula in the where clause.

Answer (score 2):

From your comment on Zackary Murphy's solution, it sounds like your `MR_ID` you want in the where is actually the computed value in the select, not the column value on the tables.  Try this.

```
SELECT 
       CONCAT(CAST(t1.MR_ID AS INT),' - ', COALESCE(t2.MR_Name, '')) AS MR_ID,
       t1.MR_ID AS sort_column, 
       CAST(Supp_ID as INT) AS Supp_ID
FROM Stage_Rebate_Index t1
      LEFT JOIN Stage_Rebate_Master t2
         ON t2.MR_ID = t1.MR_ID
WHERE  
  CONCAT(CAST(t1.MR_ID AS INT),' - ', t2.MR_Name) = LTRIM(RTRIM('$mr_id'))
ORDER BY sort_column
```

*Edit to add table aliases.

*Edit Added white space trim.

*Edit added COALESCE in case `t2.MR_Name` is null.

Comment: This works but for some reason, isnt picking up the value of `$mr_id`....i even did an `echo $mr_id` to make sure the value is being brought in properly and it is.

Comment: Do an echo on the `$sql_one` itself, I'm curious as to how that builds out.

Comment: Okay, found the problem....the format of the values is `1 - Company A`, however, when this query is run, it comes out as ` 1 - Company A `...so there is an extra space before the 1 and after A...what should it look like then?

Comment: Sounds like we just need to trim.  I'll update the query.

Comment: Whenever I echo this out and put it into my SQLPro Studio, it works...however, still nothing happens when i select a value in my dropdown...not sure why that wouldnt work

Comment: Then that sounds more line a db connection issue maybe?  Try it with the value hard coded in, see what you get.  If nothing, replace the entire query with something super simple that you know would return a value, see if it runs.  I also noticed that you are using  `Left join`.  Is if possible you are getting a null value for `t2.MR_Name`?  That might cause some weirdness.

Comment: I added a `COALESCE` to deal with nulls.  I don't think this is your issue but it is a good practice.

Comment: Correct, not the issue, but I did add it to my code just in case.

Comment: Can you edit the original post and add the query where you hard-coded the value and it worked?

Comment: Well, nothing is out of place and I can't debug any further remotely.  My hunch is that there is still a white space issue, probably before and/or after the ' - ' and probably in the `$mr_id` value itself.  It is impossible for me to know or test, just a guess.  All I can say is try to test that kind of stuff.  Good luck!

Comment: Pretty sure its a datatype problem...it works if the column is a FLOAT type but my column is VARCHAR and doesnt work...any idea with that information?

Comment: Are you saying that the `t1.MR_ID` is a varchar?

Comment: I actually was able to fix my problem...appreciate it though!

Answer (score 0):

You have to give fully qualified name of table columns.

Like you have 2 tables, table1 and table2, and have col1 as column name in both table

If you are retrieving data from these 2 table below is query example

```
select 
    table1.co11 as tbl1col1, table2.col1 as tbl2col1 
from 
    table1 
join 
    table2 on table1.id = table2.id 
where 
    table1.col1 = "your statement" and table2.col1 = "your statement"
```